# .NET Client cannot connect to to AMQP over TLS on Port 5671 Windows Server 2019 Standard version 1809

Tags: c#, ssl, rabbitmq

I am using a Windows Server 2019 Standard Version 1809 Build 17763.2803

I have first installed Erlang 26.0 (`otp_win64_26.0.exe`). I have added `Handle.exe` to PATH. I have also added `ERLANG_HOME` (value `C:\Program Files\Erlang OTP`)

Then I have installed RabbitMQ 3.12.1 (`rabbitmq-server-3.12.1.exe`). I have successfully connected to port 5672 with a .NET Client with NuGet RabbitMQ.Client 6.2.1

Then I create server certificate using tls-gen:

```bash
make PASSWORD=12345678 CN=machine.domain.local DAYS_OF_VALIDITY=3650 NUMBER_OF_PRIVATE_KEY_BITS=2048 CLIENT_ALT_NAME=machine.domain.local
```

I am installing `cacert.cer` from `tls-gen\basic\testca`

Then I am taking server certificate, key and ca_certificate.pem from `tls-gen\basic\result` and configuring them. I tried adding the password and removing it, whatever else, but for example:

```
[{rabbit,
    [
        {log_levels, [{connection, debug}, {queue, debug}]},
        {log,
            [
                {file, 
                    [
                        {level, debug}
                    ]
                },
                {categories,
                    [
                        {connection,[{level, debug}]},
                        {queue, [{level, debug}]},
                        {console, [{enabled, true},{level, debug}]}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {ssl_listeners, [5671]},
        {ssl_options, 
            [
               {cacertfile, "C:\\Program Files\\RabbitMQ Server\\rabbitmq_server-3.12.1\\certs\\ca_certificate.pem"},
               {certfile,   "C:\\Program Files\\RabbitMQ Server\\rabbitmq_server-3.12.1\\certs\\server_certificate.pem"},
               {keyfile,    "C:\\Program Files\\RabbitMQ Server\\rabbitmq_server-3.12.1\\certs\\server_key.pem"},
               {password, "12345678"}
            ]
        }        
    ]
}].
```

The client fails to connect to RabbitMQ over TLS. It throws exception:

```
RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable
 ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..)
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10054): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

I can see rabbitmq is listening on the port, however I cannot connect to it:

```
2023-06-30 18:47:28.888000+03:00 [info] <0.692.0> started TLS (SSL) listener on [::]:5671
2023-06-30 18:47:28.888000+03:00 [info] <0.712.0> started TLS (SSL) listener on 0.0.0.0:5671
2023-06-30 18:47:28.935000+03:00 [debug] <0.543.0> Plugins discovery: ignoring getopt, not a RabbitMQ plugin
2023-06-30 18:47:28.935000+03:00 [debug] <0.543.0> Plugins discovery: ignoring quantile_estimator, not a RabbitMQ plugin
2023-06-30 18:47:28.997000+03:00 [debug] <0.543.0> Plugins discovery: ignoring getopt, not a RabbitMQ plugin
2023-06-30 18:47:28.997000+03:00 [debug] <0.543.0> Plugins discovery: ignoring quantile_estimator, not a RabbitMQ plugin
2023-06-30 18:47:29.029000+03:00 [info] <0.543.0> Server startup complete; 3 plugins started.
2023-06-30 18:47:29.029000+03:00 [info] <0.543.0>  * rabbitmq_management
2023-06-30 18:47:29.029000+03:00 [info] <0.543.0>  * rabbitmq_web_dispatch
2023-06-30 18:47:29.029000+03:00 [info] <0.543.0>  * rabbitmq_management_agent
2023-06-30 18:47:29.029000+03:00 [debug] <0.543.0> Marking RabbitMQ as running
2023-06-30 18:47:29.029000+03:00 [debug] <0.543.0> Change boot state to `ready`
2023-06-30 18:47:29.029000+03:00 [debug] <0.148.0> Boot state/systemd: notifying of state `ready`
2023-06-30 18:47:29.232000+03:00 [debug] <0.9.0> Time to start RabbitMQ: 5793485 us
2023-06-30 18:47:35.164000+03:00 [debug] <0.719.0> Plugins discovery: ignoring getopt, not a RabbitMQ plugin
2023-06-30 18:47:35.164000+03:00 [debug] <0.719.0> Plugins discovery: ignoring quantile_estimator, not a RabbitMQ plugin
2023-06-30 18:48:13.260000+03:00 [notice] <0.724.0> TLS server: In state hello at tls_handshake.erl:354 generated SERVER ALERT: Fatal - Insufficient Security
2023-06-30 18:48:13.260000+03:00 [notice] <0.724.0>  - no_suitable_ciphers
```

On the server I have forbid all older TLS versions. Only TLSv1.2 is active and for now I cannot support TLSv1.3. I have allowed all of the possible cypher suites using IISCrypto. I am not certain if the issue is in the TLS Handshake due to the client and server trying to negotiate something they can't or the certificate is invalid (tls-gen says it is valid). I have done this a couple of times on Windows Server 2012 without any issues. I even tried copying certificate that is working fine from another machines, but I keep getting the error.

Comment: Note that IISCrypto has _no effect_ on OpenSSL used by Erlang.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the issue to in fact be in RabbitMQ + Erlang + OpenSSL  offering TLSv1.3 to the clients, which is not supported by the Host (Windows Server 2019 Standard Version 1809 Build 17763.2803). I have configured the queue to work only with TLSv1.2 and the issue was resolved.

I have changed to configuration to look like:

```
[{rabbit,
    [
        {log_levels, [{connection, debug}, {queue, debug}]},
        {log,
            [
                {file, 
                    [
                        {level, debug}
                    ]
                },
                {categories,
                    [
                        {connection,[{level, debug}]},
                        {queue, [{level, debug}]},
                        {console, [{enabled, true},{level, debug}]}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {ssl_listeners, [5671]},
        {ssl_options, 
            [
               {cacertfile, "C:\\Program Files\\RabbitMQ Server\\rabbitmq_server-3.12.1\\certs\\ca_certificate.pem"},
               {certfile,   "C:\\Program Files\\RabbitMQ Server\\rabbitmq_server-3.12.1\\certs\\server_certificate.pem"},
               {keyfile,    "C:\\Program Files\\RabbitMQ Server\\rabbitmq_server-3.12.1\\certs\\server_key.pem"},
               {password, "12345678"},
               {versions, ['tlsv1.2']}
            ]
        }        
    ]
}].
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a Linux/Red Hat Enterprise server running RabbitMQ 3.12.2 on Erlang 26.0.2 [jit] and Windows Server 2019 running my .NET 6 processes, where this issue appeared.

I solved the issue by adding the following line to `/etc/rabbit/rabbitmq.conf`

```
ssl_options.versions.1 = tlsv1.2
```